# CruiseControl.NET not updating build label

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

We recently switched from SVN to Git and re-configured our ccnet server.  Everything is working fine except that the build label is always 'unknown'.  This is using the lastChangeLabeller.

I can see in the log file that the label is not getting set from the last change number:

```
<CCNetLabel>unknown</CCNetLabel>
...
<LastChangeNumber>42a7436cdaeeae8f07b5ccbd369a765f2d1b55d2</LastChangeNumber>
```

I upgraded to the lastest version of ccnet (1.6.7981.1), but this is still occurring.

Update: I've tried switching to the defaultLabeller and all of the build numbers are still 'unknown'.  I didn't have this issue before, so I'm not sure why it started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally just pulled down the ccnet source code and found that the lastChangeLabeller will use 'unknown' if the LastChangeNumber cannot be parsed as an int.  So the lastChangeLabeller does not work with git.

I ended up writing my own labeller.